# Add custom claim to Laravel Passport access token

Tags: laravel, jwt

I'm manually creating my Passport access tokens, see below.
How can I add custom claims to the created token?

*In the past, where I didn't need a refresh token, I used this: https://github.com/corbosman/laravel-passport-claims*

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Response;
use \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController as ATC;

class AccessTokenController extends ATC
{
    public function issueToken(ServerRequestInterface $request)
    {
        try {
            //get username (default is :email)
            $username = $request->getParsedBody()['username'];

            //generate token
            $tokenResponse = parent::issueToken($request);

            //convert response to json string
            $content = $tokenResponse->getContent();

            //convert json to array
            $data = json_decode($content, true);

            if(isset($data["error"]))
                throw new OAuthServerException('The user credentials were incorrect.', 6, 'invalid_credentials', 401);

            //add access token to user
            $token = array();
            $token["access_token"] = $data['access_token'];
            $token["expires_in"] = $data['expires_in'];
            $token["refresh_token"] = $data['refresh_token'];

            return Response::json($token);
        }
        catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) { // email notfound
            //return error message
            return response(["message" => "User not found"], 500);
        }
        catch (OAuthServerException $e) { //password not correct..token not granted
            //return error message
            return response(["message" => "The user credentials were incorrect.', 6, 'invalid_credentials"], 500);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            ////return error message
            return response(["message" => "Internal server error"], 500);
        }
    }
}
```